# Why is $\bar{\mathbb B}^n/\mathbb S^{n-1}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^n$ and how to visualize a quotient map making the same identifications?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation, quotient-spaces

I'm currently studying Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*. In Chapter - 4 (Example 4.55), he proves that $\bar{\mathbb B}^n/\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^{n}$ using the Closed Map Lemma. I had some confusions regarding his proof.

- Firstly, how to "properly" visualize the space $\bar{\mathbb B}^n/\mathbb S^{n-1}$ ? Why does it not just look like this:
  [image]
  Since we are just collapsing the whole boundary to a single point, why is the above visualization wrong? (The figure refers to the case when $n=2$.)
- Secondly, Lee claims that the map $q:\overline{\mathbb B}^n\to\mathbb S^n$ given by $$ q(x) = \left( 2x\sqrt{1-|x|^2},2|x|^2-1 \right) $$ is a quotient map. To apply the closed map lemma, we first need to show that $q$ defined as such is actually a continuous surjective map. What's the simplest way to quickly/intuitively make this observation? How can someone come up with these maps in the first place?

TIA.

Comment: Your drawing is not clear to me, does the central point play any role? I would say that the above visualization does not satisfy visual continuity on its edge (if you take any ray, it should end at the single point you have drawn)

Comment: @JulesBesson The central point plays no role. I just forgot to remove the center after drawing the circle. I'm not sure what you mean by "visual continuity" and how it is relevant in topology.

Comment: Your representation is ok I guess, but my point is that it does not depict well how a point that approches the border of the disk comes closer to the "single point" obtained by quotienting.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, imagine the ball (e.g. in dim 2) to be a disc of fabric. On its edge (so the sphere of dim n-1 (here the circle), you sew a drawstring hem, then you pull the cord, which closes the disc on its edge, you then have a closed and empty container homeomorphic to a sphere of dimension 2

For your second question, for $|x| = 1$, you get $q(x) = (0_{n},1) = p_N$ so it is sort of a "inverted" stereographic projection of $\mathbb{S^n} \setminus p_N$ (a pole of the sphere). So if you remove $p_N$ of the sphere, you can invert $q$, then $q^{-1}$ acts like this:

It is like you made a hole at the top of your sphere (which can be of an extensible material if you want) and then enlarged it enough to flatten the whole thing on the ground, which gives you a disc.

For q, it is the inverse transformation, you take your disc (of clay for example) lift its edges, rounding it a bit with your hands progressively until the edge that has become smaller and smaller just reunites and glues to itself.

If you're not satisfied with my explanation, do the math for $n = 1$ on geogebra for example, it should be quite easy to get this afterwards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I (almost) understand how the map $q$ works now. Though your explanation of how the boundary is collapsed to form a "closed and empty container" still remains unclear to me.

Comment: Yes sorry, I don't know how to be more clear, otherwise here is a photo found on a sewing site haha <https://img.over-blog-kiwi.com/1/19/01/57/20190312/ob_bd3c8b_couture-sac-vrac-25.JPG>